# Error undefined is not an object when get value from TextInput on react native

Tags: react-native

```
class LoginComponent extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    };
  }
  onLogin() {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    alert(email);
  }
  renderInput = (
    placeholder: string,
    type: string,
    name: string,
    value: string
  ): Object => (
      <Input
        placeholder={placeholder}
        type={type}
        name={name}
        value={this.state[name] || value}
        onChangeText={({target}) => this.setState({[name]: target.value})}
      />
    ); 
   render() {
      return (
      ...
      {this.renderInput(
            "Email Address",
            "emailAddress",
            "email"
       )}
      ...
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onLogin}>
         <Text>Submit</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      )
   }
}
```

When I click Submit, error happen

[image: bug]

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your method, otherwise `this` has no scope. In your constructor add:

```js
    this.onLogin = this.onLogin.bind(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `this` to `onLogin` function.

Simple way is to use `arrow` function,

```
onLogin = () => {   //Auto binds `this`
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    alert(email);
}
```

Or you can make use of `constructor`

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    };
    this.onLogin = this.onLogin.bind(this)
}
```

**Note:**

Your `renderInput` function takes 4 arguments,

```
renderInput = (
    placeholder: string,
    type: string,
    name: string,
    value: string
  ): Object => (
```

But you are passing only 3 arguments,

```
{this.renderInput(
    "Email Address",   //This is placeholder
    "emailAddress",    //This is type
    "email"            //This is name
)}
```

Here yout `type` = `emailAddress`, we don't have `emailAddress` as type it should be `email` only.

You can simplify your input like this,

```
<Input
   placeholder={placeholder}
   type={type}
   name={name}
   value={this.state[name] || value}
   onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({[name]: text})}
/>
```

Comment: result Alert empty

Comment: This answer is correct; however consider using the constructor over lambdas as class methods; because babel does some interesting transpiling -- assuming one is using babel :)

Comment: Note that `e.target.name` and `e.target.value` are not defined for the react native `TextInput` `onChange` event (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onchange). There is no such thing as `target.name` in react native and you should use `e.nativeEvent.text` for the value.